# If "the king of France isn't bald" is not definite description

Tags: philosophy-of-language

If "the king of France isn't bald" is not definite description, but it's "a king of France isn't bald", does it not necessarily imply the existence of a king of France?

1. The king of France isn't ruling France. (definite description)
2. A king of France isn't ruling France. (non-definite description)

1 implies the existence of the king of France. (So, it has no truth value.)
2 doesn't imply the existence of a king of France. (So, it's true that a king of France isn't ruling France.)

Am I right?

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA No I want to know about non-definite  description.

Comment: What is a "non-definite description"? It is something that is not a definite description, i.e. a dog, etc. It is NOT a definite description with a not inside.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA Yes, is indefinite description like "a king isn't ruling France" true statement?

Comment: Your second sentence sounds a little odd in English and it seems to be ambiguous between, "there is a king of France who isn't ruling France," and, "there is no king ruling France". The latter does not imply existence of a king. An indefinite article with a negated predicate does not always imply existence, e.g. "a degree is not a requirement for this job", or, "a rolling stone gathers no moss".